# Installshield: include feature, but don't install or advertise

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I'm trying to figure out whether I can get InstallShield to include a feature (e.g. in the cab file) but *not* to install it, or have it appear in the custom installation dialog. The user should be unaware that this feature exists in the installer.

I want to do this because this feature (let's call if *FeatureX*) is only required if, at runtime, I determine in code that a specific licence type has been acquired. If it is, then I would prefer to uninstall a default feature (*FeatureA*) and replace it by installing *FeatureX* instead.

I can see that by setting the feature's Advertised setting to Favor Advertise, that it isn't installed by default. However, the user can still install this via a custom installation. I'd rather that it wasn't up to the user. My intention is to use something like the `MsiConfigureFeature` API to programmatically install the feature rather than have the user do it manually.

**Is there a way to get this 'on-demand installation' functionality using InstallShield?**

Is this even a sensible thing to do? Are there better ways to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: You should use "System Search" (in "behavior and logic" section) to find if the specific licence type is already installed on the computer and set a property LICENCEINSTALLED = 1 if you find it.
Then, you can create a feature "FeatureX" with the condition LICENCEINSTALLED = 1.
You can set "Display" to "Not Visible" on the Feature

Comment: A licence is only acquired once the application is running, which is obviously after installation. There is no scenaro where a licence is "already installed" at the point of installation.